# Ideals of a ring with identity

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring with identity and $I$ a (left, right or two-sided) ideal of $R$.

Demonstrate the following:

$$I=R \Longleftrightarrow I \cap R^{*} \not= \emptyset $$

where $R^{*}$ denotes the set of all invertible elements of $R$.

NOTE: In simple words, that means the ideal $ I$ is equals to  the ring $R$ if exists at least one invertible element of $R$ in $I$

**Proof:**

*Firtsly, we will prove $"\Longrightarrow"$*

$R$ is a ring with identity, then $1 \in R$. Using, $I=R$ that implies $1\in I$.

We also know $1 \in R^{*}$. Consequently, $1 \in I \cap R^{*}$ ($I \cap R^{*} \not =\emptyset$)

*Finally, we will prove $"\Longleftarrow"$*

$ I \cap R^{*} \not = \emptyset$ $\Longrightarrow$ $\exists$ $a \in I \cap R^{*}$ $\Longrightarrow$ $a \in I$ and $a \in R^{*}$

$a \in R^{*}$ $\Longrightarrow$ $\exists$ $a^{-1} \in R : aa^{-1}=a^{-1}a=1$

- If $I$ is a right ideal of $R$ **(1)**

We know, $1 = aa^{-1}$ where $ a\in I, a^{-1} \in R$. By using **(1)**, $ 1 \in I$

- If $I$ is a left ideal of $R$ **(2)**

We know, $1=a^{-1}a$ where $a^{-1} \in R, a\in I$. By using **(2)**, $1 \in I$

- If $I$ is a two-sided ideal of $R$ **(3)**

We know, $1 = aa^{-1}=a^{-1}a$ where $a \in I, a^{-1} \in R$. By using **(3)**, $1 \in I$

In all cases we conclude $1 \in I$, and that necessarily implies $ I = R$

---

Is this proof correct? I have doubts because my book says $I = R$ if and only if $I$ possesses a multiplicative inverse, but I think it must be a little mistake. It should be, **$I = R$ if and only if  $I$ possesses a multiplicative inverse of $R$**.

**Illustrative example:**

$\mathbb Z$ $\times$ $\mathbb Z$ is a ring with identity $(1,1)$ and $I =$ $\mathbb Z$ $\times$ $\{0\}$ is an ideal of $R$ with identity $(1,0)$

On one hand, following my book, that implies $I = R$ and that's obviously not true.

On the other hand, following my reasoning, $I$ no possesses multiplicative inverses of $R$ (because $(1,1),(1,-1),(-1,1),(-1,-1) \not \in I$), then $I \not = R$. And this is true !!

Comment: Regarding your example at the end: the "of $R$" is implied because ideals, in general, don't have any ring structure to speak of. In this case $I$ happens to have a ring structure, but it is not a (unital) subring of $R$ since it has a different unit. But the fact that a ring can have non-unital subrings is sort of irrelevant unless there's some ambiguity in which ring the author was talking about.

Comment: So you're right; the author does mean "if and only if $I$ possesses a multiplicative inverse of $R$," but it's also reasonable to just say "a multiplicative inverse" since there is only one ring to speak of.

Comment: Thanks for your comment!! There is something I don’t understand well. An ideal I is always a ring, because it is an “special” subring of R . Why you say:“Ideals don’t have any ring structure to speak of”?

Comment: that is not correct. An ideal is not a subring. In fact, $I\subseteq R$ is a unital subring if and only if $I=R$.

Comment: Whether or not ideals are subrings is a context dependent matter.  A lot of authors assume subrings to share identity with the superring, and some do not.  Some authors allow ideals to be considered as rings in their own right (with or without identity) and therefore as subrings of their superring.

Comment: Thanks for your comment!! I was searching information on Google and I saw exactly what you are saying. All depends of the context, the author... Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Juanma but, to be clear, no authors *require* ideals to be subrings. That's just something that can happen.

Comment: @pancini, I’m not sure. My book defines ideals as a subring of a ring with the special propertie:  “ra” and “ar” are in the ideal, where “r” is an arbitrary element of the ring and “a” an arbitrary element of the ideal. I think all depends of the author, the context, … as rschwieb said. I searched information on Google and many people consider different things, there isn’t any consensus about this topic.

Comment: Sorry I should be more specific: no authors require ideals to be *unital* subrings, and *most* authors use "subring" to mean "unital subring." Since non-unital rings are far less commonly studied than (unital) rings, most people consider "ideals" and "subrings" to be distinct ideas.

Comment: @pancini, Don’t worry! Now I have understood what were you trying to say. Thanks for help me!